# Fancybox popup loses character from parameter

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, anchor

We are using a CDN to host some of our images and resize these dynamically based on either width or height. From the product detail page we load a smaller version of the image and then have a `fancybox` link to load the 'large' version. The problem is that for parameters that contain consecutive `$` signs the second sign is lost.

```
<a rel="toolTip" class="fullImage" href="//images.acmestatic.com/Some-SEO-Image-Description-123123123.jpg?o=F38xloqGLyfcBbpwwfspkclHSSYj&V=D$$c&">Click here to see the full image</a>
```

The subsequent `fancybox` popup then renders a broken image with url:

```
<img class="fancybox-image" src="//images.acmestatic.com/Some-SEO-Image-Description-123123123.jpg?o=F38xloqGLyfcBbpwwfspkclHSSYj&V=D$c&" alt="">
```

The `V` parameter is auto generated from the description text and used as a `CRC` check to ensure the description text is not tampered with so this parameter value is calculated on the fly.

Any suggestions on where the problem might be?

Comment: have you tried using [URI Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?

Comment: did you try adding `type:"image"` to fancybpx API options?

Comment: @JFK: `type: image` is indeed specified so I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancybox (v2.x) uses an html template (`tpl`) and replaces the incoming `href` to insert it into the default or custom template, if that is the case :

```
content = current.tpl.image.replace(/\{href\}/g, href);
```

Bear in mind that the **[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method "returns a new string with some or all matches of a *pattern* replaced by a replacement".

As you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), the *pattern* `$$` inserts a `"$"`, and this is why the second sign is lost when having consecutive `$` signs.

**The workaround**

As pointed out in the comments by [@jmh2013](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284810/jmh2013), you could use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode the trailing parameter (not the full URL) **before** loading the fancybox content.

Then, you could use [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to set your trailing parameter back into the URL just **after** the template `replace()` action took place in the fancybox script.

Something like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fullImage").fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function () {
            // encode trailing parameter
            var _param = this.href.split("?");
            this.href = _param[0] + "?" + encodeURIComponent(_param[1]);
        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            $(".fancybox-image").attr("src", decodeURIComponent(this.href));
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dn3EM/)**

**NOTE**: this is for fancybox v2.x

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. We are using v2.1.4. Will try this out now.

Comment: Don't know yet. The developer is still testing